# Progress bar button

Tags: javascript, css, button, progress-bar

I want this type of Animated Progress Button : [image]
there will be a heart image of left section of button and right section will empty for progress bar, if we click on the heart image the image should be changed and the prgress bar will load from the right section.

I have tried many times but i cant , Here is my code

```js
document.getElementById('heartButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const heartIcon = document.getElementById('heartIcon');
  const brokenHeartIcon = document.getElementById('brokenHeartIcon');
  const progressBar = document.querySelector('.progress-bar');

  // Hide the heart image and display the broken heart image
  heartIcon.style.display = 'none';
  brokenHeartIcon.style.display = 'block';

  // Animate progress bar
  progressBar.style.width = '100%';

  // Reset button after animation
  setTimeout(function() {
    progressBar.style.width = '0';

    // Toggle back to the original state
    heartIcon.style.display = 'block';
    brokenHeartIcon.style.display = 'none';
  }, 1000); // Change the duration as needed
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #3498db;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left-section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#heartIcon,
#brokenHeartIcon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#brokenHeartIcon {
  display: none;
}

.right-section {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  transition: width 1s linear;
  /* Use linear transition for smooth animation */
}
```

```html
<button id="heartButton">
  <div class="left-section">
    <img src="love.png" alt="Heart Icon" id="heartIcon">
    <img src="heartbroken.png" alt="Broken Heart Icon" id="brokenHeartIcon">
  </div>
  <div class="right-section">
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
  </div>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

in progress bar change 'left' to 'right'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `.progress-bar` has `position: absolute` and the closest parent with relative position is the button element.

If you don't want the progress bar to overlap the whole button, adding `postition: relative` to `.right-section` might just do the trick